# Bootstrap navbars increase in height on collapse

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm new to bootstrap and have a problem maintaining line-height when collapsing these header and footer navbars...

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-inverse">
      <div class="container-fluid no-padding">

<!-- header navbar -->
<div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar" style = "line-height: 30px;">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-hamburger"></span>
          </button>
          <a href="#" class="pull-left">
            <img height="35px;" src="image/companyLogo.png" style="margin-left: 5px;">
          </a> 
         <a class="navbar-brand" href="#" style = "line-height: 30px; margin-left: 1px;">Company Name</a> 
</div>

<!-- footer navbar -->
<div class="nav navbar-default navbar-fixed-bottom" style="background-color: #ADD6FF; font-size: 11px;">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav" style = "float:right;">
            <li><a href="#">Copyright &#169; 2015</a></li>
          </ul>
</div>
```

With these CSS overrides...

```
.navbar-nav li a {
 line-height: 20px;
}

.navbar-header {
 line-height: 30px;
}
```

What's happening is that regardless of what I set the CSS to, when the page collapses they always increase (from the looks of things by around 5-10 pixels).  So I've been searching through the default bootstrap css file for some kind of padding variable that's being added on collapse but I can't find anything.

Any ideas what I might be doing wrong here?  Even a general idea of a better way to try and isolate the problem?  I should also add that I downloaded a customised version of bootstrap with the 30px navbar height.

Thanks for any thoughts at all!

Comment: codepan or Snipset will be lot helpful

Comment: Hi Abdulla, here you go: http://codepen.io/d3wannabe/pen/jbrQMo.  I couldn't get the hambuger glyphicon working on codepen but interestingly that kept the navbar-header at a fixed size on collapse (no idea why yet) - so it's just the footer I have a problem with now.  Thanks for taking the time to look at this.

Comment: Isn't this because the `.navbar-toggle` becomes visible? see [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/12308/), -edit: nvm: codepen explains more clearly what the issue is.

Comment: thanks Lars - guess that explains the header problem - although in my codepen strangely enough the "Company name" and logo also get moved to the left which doesn't seem to happen in yours (correctly).  That's another thing that was bothering me - why my company name text moves on collapse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line height issue isn't the toggle itself, it from being replaced with a Glyphicon that making the navbar push down once you're below 768px.

As far as the other elements being re-positioned (like the image), it's because you're removing the padding from the `container-fluid` along with where the image is placed inside the header as well. These all change with regard to the viewport by default so if you don't account for them it can get messy.

There are also CSS rules that seem to be repeated/redundant so there's some conflict there as well (or not reaching the correct selectors). See example.

```css
html {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100%;
}
body,
html {
  margin-top: 125px;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}
.footer {
  vertical-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #ADD6FF;
  padding: 12px 0;
}
ul.footer-nav > li {
  margin-top: 5px;
  list-style: none;
  vertical-align: center;
  text-align: right;
}
ul.footer-nav > li > a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #444444;
}
.navbar.navbar-custom {
  border-radius: 0px;
  background: #33CC33;
  border: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
}
.navbar-custom .navbar-nav > li > a {
  color: #fff;
}
.navbar-custom .navbar-brand {
  color: #fff;
}
.navbar-custom .navbar-logo {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 15px;
}
.navbar-custom .navbar-header .navbar-toggle {
  background: none;
  border: none;
  line-height: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 0;
}
.navbar-custom .navbar-header .navbar-toggle:hover,
.navbar-custom .navbar-header .navbar-toggle:focus {
  background: none;
  border: none;
}
.navbar-custom .navbar-header .navbar-toggle .glyphicon-menu-hamburger,
.navbar-custom .navbar-header .navbar-toggle .glyphicon-menu-hamburger:hover,
.navbar-custom .navbar-toggle .navbar-header .glyphicon-menu-hamburger:focus {
  color: #F0C425;
}
.navbar-custom .navbar-header .navbar-toggle .navbar-custom .navbar-right {
  margin-right: 15px;
}
.navbar-default .lower-nav {
  border: none;
  border-radius: 0px;
  background: #ADD6FF;
  border: none;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
.navbar-default .lower-nav .nav-buttons {
  margin: 5px 10px;
  top: 5px;
  border-radius border-radius: 0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container-fluid">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-custom navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-navbar"> <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-hamburger"></span>

      </button>
      <a class="navbar-logo" href="#">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/100x50/ff0/ff0">
      </a><a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>

    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-navbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a>

        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default lower-nav" role="navigation">
      <div class="btn-group pull-left">
        <div class="btn btn-link nav-buttons"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>

        </div>
        <div class="btn btn-link nav-buttons"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cloud"></span>

        </div>
        <div class="btn btn-link nav-buttons"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></span>

        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </nav>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="alert alert-info"> <a href="http://getbootstrap.com//">Bootstrap 3</a> 
  </div>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras ultrices enim id tortor tincidunt, eget mollis mauris gravida. Mauris sem leo, feugiat ut felis blandit, imperdiet egestas orci. Proin lacinia at massa fermentum facilisis. Donec laoreet
    facilisis nunc, sed posuere magna rhoncus sed. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Praesent augue ipsum, rhoncus vel tempus sed, vehicula non purus. Nunc sit amet consectetur risus. Integer eget justo ut sapien consectetur
    auctor id eu augue. Quisque ac elit congue, eleifend lectus a, tempor purus. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Phasellus gravida massa arcu, sed sodales orci interdum vel. Curabitur ullamcorper leo mauris, ut interdum felis mollis id. Nunc porttitor
    egestas fringilla. Suspendisse volutpat sem quis sagittis fermentum. Fusce in laoreet elit. Etiam aliquam varius tincidunt.</p>
  <p>Nunc nisi justo, ultricies at lobortis et, fermentum at dolor. Nulla ultrices erat et erat egestas, in luctus justo pellentesque. In convallis purus ut pellentesque interdum. Curabitur in neque lectus. Nullam lobortis sodales elit, eu fringilla eros
    aliquet vel. Aliquam ac ipsum vel nunc vestibulum luctus nec sit amet mauris. Ut viverra ornare risus eu condimentum. Fusce sollicitudin volutpat nisl id dignissim. Sed malesuada dui at magna imperdiet, non accumsan odio imperdiet. Etiam tristique
    fermentum enim, vel dictum nulla fermentum ac. Etiam in bibendum nisi. Vestibulum neque lectus, vehicula eu sagittis ut, blandit sit amet mi.</p>
  <p>Maecenas lacinia vestibulum magna. Integer mollis varius ullamcorper. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Nullam sit amet tortor turpis. Cras pharetra tellus elit, nec iaculis erat pellentesque
    sit amet. Nullam varius felis vel velit fermentum, nec facilisis erat accumsan. Nullam facilisis orci quam, eget semper turpis dictum id. Aenean magna ante, lobortis id sollicitudin quis, dapibus nec nisi. Maecenas aliquet posuere lectus, a ultricies
    arcu sodales sodales. Proin dignissim facilisis consectetur. Pellentesque suscipit quis dui eget malesuada. Quisque cursus neque a faucibus egestas. Phasellus sed nulla scelerisque diam adipiscing suscipit. Etiam sit amet enim ultricies risus consequat
    vestibulum eu sit amet urna.</p>
  <p>Vivamus hendrerit eget augue viverra auctor. Praesent mi leo, facilisis vel nisi vitae, sodales rhoncus augue. Maecenas purus nunc, commodo at massa eu, blandit aliquet enim. Proin sem neque, imperdiet non arcu eu, sagittis malesuada est. Fusce enim
    neque, facilisis et mattis ut, vulputate sed justo. Vivamus elementum elit nunc, eget tempor erat adipiscing nec. Praesent vestibulum dapibus vehicula. Pellentesque viverra faucibus leo in ornare. Sed sodales faucibus tincidunt. Vivamus dignissim
    tristique libero sit amet aliquet. Donec ut nunc dolor. Duis molestie tortor mi, id auctor nisi ullamcorper et. Proin eu ante cursus, varius felis id, porta orci.</p>
  <p>Aliquam imperdiet scelerisque purus, nec sagittis mi auctor vitae. Maecenas sodales scelerisque massa, vitae iaculis neque tincidunt sed. Vivamus id imperdiet lectus. Fusce id tellus ut tellus volutpat hendrerit in at justo. Duis eu tempus nibh. Nunc
    consectetur euismod sapien, eget placerat metus tempor sit amet. Maecenas at sem ac purus dictum viverra. Praesent eu neque in metus congue dictum eu in dolor. Mauris a elit sem. Quisque non velit malesuada ligula aliquet lacinia. Donec congue, leo
    lacinia vulputate pulvinar, est justo venenatis nisi, sit amet condimentum massa sem sed urna. Duis eget pretium eros. Sed et rutrum leo, sit amet sollicitudin urna. Nullam dui augue, malesuada sed lectus sed, malesuada fringilla massa.</p>
  <div class="alert alert-danger"> <a href="#">Start the Footer</a> 
  </div>
</div>
<footer class="footer">
  <div class="container">
    <ul class="footer-nav">
      <li><a href="#">Copyright &#169; 2015</a>

      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 1):

`.navbar-toggle` becomes visible, it's size and margins causes the `.navbar` to grow.

In the codepen `.navbar-header` is styled like:

```
@media (min-width: 768px)
{
  margin-right: 0;
  margin-left: 0;
}

.navbar-header
{
  margin-right: -15px;
  margin-left: -15px;
}
```

which is causing the logo to move.